# Problema em dar Git Push em repositório (com outras pessoas)

Tags: javascript, git, github

Resumidamente, já tentei dar `git push`, `git pull`, aceitar as mudanças, já dei `commit`, `git push --set-upstream origin main`, `git push -u origin main`.

Erro abaixo se não puder abrir a imagem:

```
! [rejected] main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/BrenoPierin/Edux_ReactNative.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

[image: Erro que está dando]

Comment: Use `git pull origin main`

Answer (score 1):

O erro é autoexplicativo:

"As atualizações foram rejeitadas porque o seu branch atual está atrás de sua contraparte remota. Integre as alterações remotas (por exemplo, 'git pull ...') antes de fazer o push novamente."

Como você esta na brach `main` use `git pull origin main`, isso vai atualizar o seu repositório local. Depois você vai conseguir executar `git push -u origin main`

Answer (score 0):

Antes de tudo você deve fazer o commit das suas mudanças com os seguintes comandos:

```
git add .
git commit -m "mensagem"
```

E depois usar o comando:

```
git pull origin main
```

Se estiver usando vs code, vai aparecer no código as mudanças para você aceitar.